# Domain registrar that offers CNAME settings

Tags: web-hosting, cname, cloud-hosting

I have looked and couldn't find one. Please recommend a domain registrar on which you can change CNAME settings without having a hosting account.

I have to change CNAME setting for my domain to make it point to a cloud hosting service http://www.openshift.com. Openshift doesn't yet offer domain registering so I have to use another registrar bit most seem to have CNAME settings only for hosting...

Comment: I think you mean "registrar". _You_ are the "registrant".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am a bit confused by the question. However I am assuming that your domain name is hosted within a DNS service and your site is hosted with another company. This is not uncommon.

GoDaddy allows this just fine. You can host your domain name there and do whatever you want with the DNS settings. I do this. My site is not hosted. Just my DNS records.

Answer (score 2):

Most of the domain registrars provide this feature. You can manage your DNS records without hosting it. There is no additional cost for it and it can be managed from the dashboard of the provider.

Before registering a domain, check with the Sales team if they provide with this feature.